# Hadoop node taking a long time to decommission

Tags: hadoop

EDIT: I finally figured out what the issue was. Some files had very high replication factor set, and I was reducing my cluster to 2 nodes. Once I reduced my replication factor on those files, the decommissioning successfully ended quickly.

I've added the node to be decommissioned in the `dfs.hosts.exclude` and `mapred.hosts.exclude` files, and executed this command:

`bin/hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes`.

In the NameNode UI, I see this node under `Decommissioning Nodes`, but it's taking too long time, and I don't have much data on the node being decommissioned.

Does it always take a very long time to decommision nodes or is there some place I should be looking? I'm not sure what is exactly going on.

I don't see any corrupted blocks also on this node:

```
$ ./hadoop/bin/hadoop fsck -blocks /
 Total size:    157254687 B
 Total dirs:    201
 Total files:   189 (Files currently being written: 6)
 Total blocks (validated):      140 (avg. block size 1123247 B) (Total open file blocks (not validated): 1)
 Minimally replicated blocks:   140 (100.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:        6 (4.285714 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:       12 (8.571428 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    2
 Average block replication:     1.9714285
 Corrupt blocks:                0
 Missing replicas:              88 (31.884058 %)
 Number of data-nodes:          3
 Number of racks:               1
FSCK ended at Mon Jul 22 14:42:45 IST 2013 in 33 milliseconds


The filesystem under path '/' is HEALTHY

$ ./hadoop/bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 25357025280 (23.62 GB)
Present Capacity: 19756299789 (18.4 GB)
DFS Remaining: 19366707200 (18.04 GB)
DFS Used: 389592589 (371.54 MB)
DFS Used%: 1.97%
Under replicated blocks: 14
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 3 (3 total, 0 dead)

Name: 10.40.11.107:50010
Decommission Status : Decommission in progress
Configured Capacity: 8452341760 (7.87 GB)
DFS Used: 54947840 (52.4 MB)
Non DFS Used: 1786830848 (1.66 GB)
DFS Remaining: 6610563072(6.16 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.65%
DFS Remaining%: 78.21%
Last contact: Mon Jul 22 14:29:37 IST 2013


Name: 10.40.11.106:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 8452341760 (7.87 GB)
DFS Used: 167412428 (159.66 MB)
Non DFS Used: 1953377588 (1.82 GB)
DFS Remaining: 6331551744(5.9 GB)
DFS Used%: 1.98%
DFS Remaining%: 74.91%
Last contact: Mon Jul 22 14:29:37 IST 2013


Name: 10.40.11.108:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 8452341760 (7.87 GB)
DFS Used: 167232321 (159.49 MB)
Non DFS Used: 1860517055 (1.73 GB)
DFS Remaining: 6424592384(5.98 GB)
DFS Used%: 1.98%
DFS Remaining%: 76.01%
Last contact: Mon Jul 22 14:29:38 IST 2013
```

Answer (score 7):

Decommissioning is not an instant process, even if you don't have much data.

First, when you decommission that means that the data has to be replicated quite a few blocks (depends on how large your block size is), and this could easily overwhelm your cluster and cause operational issues, so I believe this is somewhat throttled.

Also, depending on which Hadoop version you use, the thread that monitors decomissions only wakes up every so often. It used to be around 5 minutes in the earlier versions of Hadoop, but I believe now this is every minute or less.

**Decommission in progress** means that the blocks are being replicated, so I guess this really depends how much data you have, and you just have to wait since this won't be utilizing your cluster fully for this task.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I finally figured out what the issue was. Some files had very high replication factor set, and I was reducing my cluster to 2 nodes. Once I reduced my replication factor on those files, the decommissioning successfully ended quickly.

Comment: Is it safe to remove a datanode after the missing blocks has become 0? Even though there is underreplication that can be managed via other replicas right?

Answer (score 1):

While decommissioning in progress, temporary or staging files get cleaned automatically.  These files are missing now and hadoop is not recognizing how that went missing.  So the decommissioning process keeps waiting until that is resolved even though the actual decommissioning is done for all the other files.

In Hadoop GUI - if you notice the parameter "Number of Under-Replicated Blocks" is not reducing over the time or almost constant then this is the reason likely.

So list the files using below command

hadoop fsck / -files -blocks -racks

If you see those files are temporary and not required then delete those files or folder

Example: hadoop fs  -rmr  /var/local/hadoop/hadoop/.staging/*  (give the correct path here)

This would solve the problem immediately. De-commissioned nodes will move to Dead Nodes in 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the status won't change or will take ages (and fail eventually) if you do not have more active datanodes than the replication factor in file level or default level.